# Routing in a nested React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I ask you not to throw stones, because everyone once studied) The bottom line is this: I am writing a wishlist for myself and my friends, and I got stuck at a seemingly very stupid moment. The nested component is a header with navigation tabs and an exit button. While I am implementing the framework of the application, therefore, authorization occurs simply by loggedInUser /!loggedInUser. Actually, when you click on the exit button, an empty string is dispatched in loggedInUser and history.push ('/ login'). In the debugger, I see that the dispatch is happening and the location is pushed to the history, but for some reason, the rendering condition will not be fulfilled. I ask the help of knowledgeable people. I suppose that I messed up with routing somewhere, since I read that BrowserRouter for some reason is not used, but without it nothing works at all. In general, thanks in advance!

Entry:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Routing component:

```
interface AppProps {
    loggedInUser: string;
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps & RouteComponentProps> {
    state = { 
        loggedInUser: ""
    }

    render() {
        const history = this.props
        return (
            <>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Segment>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route history={history} path='/login' render={() => (!this.props.loggedInUser ? <LoginPage /> : <Redirect to="/account" />)}/>
                            <Route history={history} path='/account' render={() => (this.props.loggedInUser ? <AccountPage/> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}/>
                            <Route history={history} path='/friendslist' render={() => (this.props.loggedInUser ? <FriendsList/> : <Redirect to="/login" />)}/>
                            <Redirect from='/' to='/login' />
                        </Switch>
                    </Segment>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: StateInterface): AppProps => ({
    loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(App))
```

Nested component (it is rendered in each of the routed components):

```
interface HeaderProps extends HeaderPropsFromState{
    activeItem: string;
}

interface HeaderPropsFromState{
    loggedInUser: string;
}


class Header extends React.Component<HeaderProps & RouteComponentProps> {
    state = { 
        activeItem: this.props.activeItem,
    }

    handleItemClick = (e: any, { name }: any) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

    render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state
        const { match, history } = this.props
                return (
            <Menu pointing>
                        <Menu.Item
                            name='Friends'
                            active={activeItem === 'Friends'}
                            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
                            as={Link}
                            to="/friendslist"
                        />
                        <Menu.Item
                            name='Account'
                            active={activeItem === 'Account'}
                            onClick={this.handleItemClick}
                            as={Link}
                            to="/account"
                        />
                        {activeItem === 'Friends' &&
                            <Menu.Menu position='right'>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    <Input icon='users' iconPosition='left' placeholder='Search users...' />
                                    {/* TODO: create function to filter by friend's name */}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu.Menu>
                        }
                        {activeItem === 'Account' &&
                            <Menu.Menu position='right'>
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    <Button basic 
                                    color='black'
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        console.log(this.props.loggedInUser)
                                        store.dispatch(setLoggedInUser({username: ""}))
                                        history.push('/login')
                                    }}
                                    >Exit</Button>
                                    {/* TODO: create function to exit from account */}
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu.Menu>
                        }
                    </Menu>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: StateInterface): HeaderPropsFromState => ({
    loggedInUser: state.loggedInUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withRouter(Header))
```

[image: Image just for better understanding]

UPD: Component that includes the header component.

```
class FriendsList extends React.Component{
    users = [...users objects]

    render() {
        const usersList = this.users.map((user: User, index: number) =>
                <OneFriendWishes user={user} key={index}/>
            )
        return (
            <>
                <Header activeItem={"Friends"}/>
                {usersList}
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default FriendsList
```

Comment: where did you place your header component? Also, it has nothing to do with the Browser Router as it creates some problems in production for which you can use a hash router or handle it from the backend.

Comment: As I said - the header component is placed in each of the routed components. Now I will attach an example to the question.

Comment: you don't need to place the header in every component...that's a bad approach.. instead make the header component outside of the routes.. and also you don't need withRouter on every component which are inside the Router.

Comment: Yes, I generally understood this when I did it, but in this way I solved the problem with displaying the header on the authorization page :D

Comment: thanks btw, I will try to solve auth page problem at first